# Hello! How to do this with a function for date and year?

Tags: sql

--7. Create a query which lists out all of the events which took place in February 2005:--

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEvent
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '2005-02-01' AND '20050228';
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Column EventDate data type?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify syntax is to build a function-based index (FBI) on the date column as shown below:

```
create index
   index_name
on
   tblEvent
(to_char(EventDate, 'Mon-YYYY')):

select
  *
from
   tblEvent
where
to_char(EventDate,'Mon-YYYY')='Feb-2005';
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEvent WHERE year(EventDate)=2005 and month(EventDate)=2
```

in SQL Server